# how to group data set without overwrite data in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to set of the employee attendance date prepare by the following order.

```
row data

emp_no  date                time
001   2019-08-07 00:00:00    1899-12-30 08:29:28
001   2019-08-07 00:00:00    1899-12-30 17:29:28
```

I want to prepare like and save in anther table

```
emp_no    date      time_in   time_out
001     2019-08-07 08:29:28   17:29:28

time in 03:00 am - 12:15 pm
time out 12:15 pm to 03:00 am
```

row data get by finger print machine.
2000 employee detail are record by day. how to solve this problem?i try to group by according emp_no and date but get wrong output 
I am using php and MySQL for development

Comment: what if emp_no 001 will time_out the next day?

Comment: what's the mysql version?

Comment: it also need to be considerable.

Comment: mysql version-4.8.5

Comment: another instance is that if employee got 3 entries in a day.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and show us real sample data which covers all these edge cases.

Comment: no need to consider above case

Comment: okay i will edit my post

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

1. If you need to save in new table then, first create new_table
2. Insert formatted data in new_table from your main table
3. select all data from new_table

```
    create table new_table(emp_no number,
                           day_date date,
                           time_in varchar2(15),
                           time_out varchar2(15));

    insert into new_table 
    select emp_no,
           date,
           extract(hour from min(time)) || ':' || extract(minute from min(time)) || ':' || extract(second from min(time)),
           extract(hour from max(time)) || ':' || extract(minute from max(time)) || ':' || extract(second from max(time))
      from employee
    group by emp_no, date;

    select * from new_table;
```

Although I am not sure what you are deriving below data

```
time in 03:00 am - 12:15 pm
time out 12:15 pm to 03:00 am
```

Comment: time in 03:00 am - 12:15 pm
time out 12:15 pm to 03:00 am  mean if time is between 03:00 am - 12:15 pm it should me record as time in of the particular employee .if the time is between 12:15 pm to 03:00 am record as time out of the particular employee.how do apply this logic in sql statement

Comment: any way much appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea. Get the row numbers per emp_no sorted by empno, date and time. then left join the time_out (2nd entry) to you first table.

```
SELECT t1.emp_no, t1.date, t1.time as time_in, IFNULL(t2.type, 'no time out') as time_out FROM (SELECT 
      @row_number:=CASE
          WHEN @id = emp_no THEN @row_number + 1
          ELSE 1
      END AS num,
      @id:=emp_no as emp_no,
      date,
      time
  FROM
      table1,(SELECT @id:=0,@row_number:=0) as t
  ORDER BY emp_no, date, time) as t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
      @row_number:=CASE
          WHEN @id = emp_no THEN @row_number + 1
          ELSE 1
      END AS num,
      @id:=emp_no as emp_no,
      date,
      time
  FROM
      table1,(SELECT @id:=0,@row_number:=0) as t
  ORDER BY emp_no, date, time) as t2 on t2.num - 1 = t1.num and t2.emp_no = t1.emp_no
WHERE mod(t1.num, 2) = 1
```

Comment: how to check the time in and time out condition

Comment: I suggest not to consider timeout conditions if you want your query to be flexible to any business rules. let say we have 3 entries, so the 1st is the entry time, 2nd is the time out, 3rd is another entry in 1 day.

Comment: but some time time out may be in next day. previously i gave you wrong idea.sorry for that.i have to consider the 3 rd entity also.i need the build query base on the time logic .is it possible or not?