# How to group the data set without removing the duplication value

Tags: mysql, sql

[attendence sql file in here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-X9_6aR7HzWIu-MXjl4FN4U7J7GKgYoQ/view?usp=sharing)i want group the data set without remove the duplication value.

i try to following query .i can only one time relate to one day.

```
    SELECT 
        EnrolledID,
        Date,
        CASE WHEN Time > '1899-12-30 03:00:00' && Time <= '1899-12-30 12:15:00' THEN Time 
        END AS time_in ,
        CASE WHEN Time > '1899-12-30 12:15:00' && Time <= '1899-12-30 23:59:59' THEN Time 
        END AS time_out
    from attendance
        GROUP BY EnrolledID ;
```

Output of above query

```
EnrolledID      Date                time_in                 time_out    
23          2019-08-01 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:54:40     NULL    
23          2019-08-01 00:00:00     NULL                    1899-12-30 16:01:40 
23          2019-08-02 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:42:35      NULL   
23          2019-08-02 00:00:00    NULL                     1899-12-30 16:02:53 
23          2019-08-03 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:37:41      NULL
```

Expected output.

```
EnrolledID      Date                time_in                 time_out    
    23          2019-08-01 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:54:40     1899-12-30 16:01:40 
    23          2019-08-01 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:42:35                 1899-12-30 16:01:40 
    23          2019-08-02 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:42:35     1899-12-31 16:15:33 
    23          2019-08-02 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:11:51                     1899-12-30 16:02:53 
    23          2019-08-03 00:00:00     1899-12-30 07:37:41      1899-12-31 16:15:00
```

Comment: So this is your expected output, or output you are getting from above query.

Comment: not expected output.link image show the original data set .i want replace the NULL value place according my data set

Comment: there is two time occur one date and empno .but in gruop process one record has been missing.how to avoid the duplication remover

Comment: which version of mysql you are using

Comment: @Nipun Sachinda show your `attendance` map

Comment: i add the attendance sql file

Comment: Why are you using dates from the 19th Century?  Especially for `time_out`.  If the value doesn't exist, just use `NULL`.

Comment: 1899-12-30 is default date .it is not effect to the time caluclation

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. Since you already have your `time in` and `time out` in your query, so you may easily get your desired result using `union all`.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT COUNT(Date) 
    EnrolledID,
    Date,
    CASE WHEN Time > '1899-12-30 03:00:00' && Time <= '1899-12-30 12:15:00' THEN Time 
    END AS time_in ,
    CASE WHEN Time > '1899-12-30 12:15:00' && Time <= '1899-12-30 23:59:59' THEN Time 
    END AS time_out
from attendance
    GROUP BY EnrolledID 
)
, CT AS (
    SELECT  EnrolledID, DATE, TIME_IN AS TIME FROM CTE WHERE TIME_IN IS NOT NULL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  EnrolledID, DATE, TIME_OUT FROM CTE WHERE TIME_OUT IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT EnrolledID, DATE , TIME FROM CTE ORDER BY DATE, TIME
```

If they have multiple records for each date and you want only certain record then you may apply the same filter under `ct` section to get the desired output.

Although if you share your table schema and sample output then it is better to provide any suggestion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57404842/how-to-group-data-set-without-overwrite-data-in-sql

Comment: this is one way solve this question.how can i share with sql file?

Comment: what do you mean by `how can i share with sql file`.

Comment: i add the attendence table sql schema.

Comment: @NipunSachinda: this is question has our answer, as expected. kindly post new question for this case, since it is totally different from what is asked at first. You can mark it as accepted and ask new question for that.